# Django - Empty session data in ajax requests

Tags: ajax, django, session, request

I have an ajax view where I want to set a session variable like such:

```
def upload(request, *args, **kwargs):  
    request.session['test'] = 'test'  
    request.session.modified = True  
    print request.session.items()
```

I have another normal view something like this:

```
def advertise(request):  
    print request.session.items()
```

I get these two dicts printed to shell:

```
[('test', 'test')]  
[('_auth_user_backend', 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'), ('_auth_user_id', 26L)]
```

Why is the session data that I set in the ajax view not passing to my regular views? If I set session data in regular view, everything works as fine, but it seems that ajax requests contain empty session data? Anybody dealt with something like this before? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just a little suggestion. Try to use the Django Debug Toolbar and look if you can find any hints as to where the problem is. You can download it here: http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar. Hope that helps you.

Comment: Do You send same session ID to the server (via cookie)?

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same problem today. Although I don't think the OP is still waiting for an answer after 3 months :-), this might help others.

I was sending out Ajax requests like this...

`$.ajax({url: 'http://localhost:8000/testgame/getTime/', 
        async: false, dataType: 'text', 
        success: function(text) { 
            time = new Date(text); 
        }, error: function(http, message, exc) { 
            time = new Date(); 
    }});`

...and accessing the application in Firefox like this:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/config/`

And the problem was that localhost and 127.0.0.1 are not the same in this case!

Comment: Thanks! I was running into the same problem and it was driving me a little crazy. :)

Comment: Wow, can't believe I wasted hours on the difference between localhost and 127.0.0.1 .... they should be the same >_<

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711565/django-session-key-different-on-each-ajax-call