# django session_key different on each ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-sessions

I've got a django application that I am accessing only over AJAX. My main problem is I want to get a unique ID which pairs to a particular browser instance making the request.

To try to do this, I'm trying to access the `session_key` that django creates, but it's sometimes coming back as `None`.

Here's how I'm creating the JSON response in django:

```py
def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
    resp_obj = {}
    ...
    resp_obj['csrftoken'] = csrftoken
    # shouldn't need the next two lines, but request.session.session_key is None sometimes
    if not request.session.exists(request.session.session_key):
        request.session.create()
    resp_obj['sessionid'] = request.session.session_key
    return JSONResponse(resp_obj)
```

When I make the request using Postman, the `session_key` comes through in both the JSON body and in the cookie, but when I make the request through jquery in a browser, `request.session.session_key` is None, which is why I added these lines:

```
if not request.session.exists(request.session.session_key):
    request.session.create()
```

But when I do that, the `session_key` is different each time.

Here's how I'm making the AJAX call:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < this.survey_ids.length; i++) {
  $.ajax({
    url: this.SERVER_URL+ '/surveys/' + this.survey_ids[i] + '/?language=' + VTA.user_language,
    headers: {
      'Accept-Language': user_language
    }
  }).error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // handle the error
  }).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    window.console.log(response.csrftoken)  // different on each iteration
    window.console.log(response.sessionid)  // also different on each iteration

    //handle response

  })
}
```

The Django documentation says that sessions are not always created:

> By default, Django only saves to the session database when the session has been modified – that is if any of its dictionary values have been assigned or deleted
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved

Is there a way to force django `session_key` creation even when is session not modified, but not have it change when it shouldn't? Or is there a way to "modify the session" such that it gets created properly like Postman is doing?

Comment: [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY) link suggests that you need to set this parameter, to receive same session requests from JS.

Comment: I see.. I tried that and it didn't work. Still getting different keys back.

Comment: Just a sanity check: `this.SERVER_URL` matches the URL in the browser address bar? e.g. `localhost:8000` != `127.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: It does not. This is going to be cross origin

Comment: In that case, shouldn't your Ajax request be setting the cross origin headers?

`crossDomain: true,`

Comment: @OozeMeister I don't know, should it? When I add that, the browser returns `Request header field crossDomain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`... I do have `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` in my django settings using the corsheaders middleware

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this @KyleFalconer? I'm having the same issue currently. I want to set a session variable through ajax, but get a different session for every ajax call.

Comment: @Richard It's been a while since I looked at the code, and unfortunately I don't think I found a bulletproof solution, but what I ended up doing is using a combination of the requester's IP address and the timestamp so I could later merge them together. The commit is here if you want to check it out: https://github.com/vta/OpenSurvey/commit/208c9b2b36c1f110a79d6fe20deabcb00b03ba8c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem basically comes from the cross-domain part of your request. I copied your example, and tried by accessing the main page with `localhost`, then sending the `Ajax` request on `localhost` as well, and the session key is conserved.

However, when I change the `Ajax` request to be on `127.0.0.1` (and with a proper configuration of `django-cors-headers`), I can get the exact same issue as what you describe. The session key is changed for each request. (The CSRF token as well, but this is on purpose, and should be kept this way.)

Here, you have a mix of [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), third-party [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies), and credentials in `XMLHttpRequest` which makes the whole thing break.

## What exactly is happening?

### Context

First, let's agree on the content of your files.

```
# views.py
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.middleware import csrf

def ajax_call(request):
    if not request.session.exists(request.session.session_key):
        request.session.create()
    # To debug the server side
    print request.session.session_key
    print csrf.get_token(request)

    # To debug the client side
    resp_obj = {}
    resp_obj['sessionid'] = request.session.session_key
    resp_obj['csrf'] = csrf.get_token(request)
    return JsonResponse(resp_obj)
```

The Javascript code included in a larger HTML page:

```
# Javascript, client side
function call () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1/ajax_call/'
    }).fail(function () {
        console.log("Error");
    }).done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(response.sessionid);
        console.log(response.csrf);
    })
}
```

Note the Ajax request is made on `127.0.0.1`, and not on `localhost`, as it is in your case. (Or maybe, you access the main HTML page on `127.0.0.1` and use `localhost` in the Ajax call, but the idea is the same.)

Finally, you allow `CORS` in `settings.py` by adding the adequate lines in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE` (see [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) for more info on the installation). To make it easy, you allow all URLs, and all `ORIGIN` by adding these lines:

```
# settings.py
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_URLS_REGEX = True
```

> Do not copy these lines on a production server if you do not understand what it does! It can open a sever security breech.

### Mechanisms

1. Your browser sends a `GET` request to the main page (let's imagine it is the root of the website, and the request is `GET http://localhost`)

Here, it does not really matter if a session is open between your browser and `localhost`, as the state probably won't change.

The server sends back the HTML page with the Javascript code included.

2. Your browser interprets the Javascript code. It creates an `XMLHttpRequest`, which is sent to the server at the address `http://127.0.0.1/ajax_call`. If a session was previously open with `localhost`, it cannot be used here, because the domain name is not the same. Anyway, it does not matter, as the session can be created when answering this request.
3. The server receives a request for `127.0.0.1`. If you did not add this host as an allowed-host in your `settings.py` and you run your server in production mode, an exception is raised. End of the story. If you run in `DEBUG` mode, the server creates a new session, as none was sent by the client. Everything goes as expected, a new `session_key` and a new `CSRF token` are created, and sent to the client in the header. Let's look at that more precisely.

Here is an example of the header sent by the browser:

```
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost/
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Cookie: csrftoken=XCadvu4MJjDMzCkOTTC276oJs9P0j989CBw6rnidz7cS34PoOt1VftqWMqd8BHMX; django_language=en
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Look closely at the `Cookie` line. No `sessionid` is sent, because no session is open.

The header sent back by the server looks like that, if everything went well.

```
Content-Length: 125
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sun, 17 Sep 2017 14:21:23 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.14rc1
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=XCadvu4MJjDMzCkOTTC276oJs9P0j989CBw6rnidz7cS34PoOt1VftqWMqd8BHMX; expires=Sun, 16-Sep-2018 14:21:22 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
sessionid=l505q4y8pywe9t3q76204662a1225scx; expires=Sun, 01-Oct-2017 14:21:22 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
Vary: Cookie
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
```

The server created a session, and sent all the needed information to the client, as a `Set-Cookie` header. Looks good !

4. The behavior we expect from the browser is that it sets the cookie for the domain 127.0.0.1, and uses it for the next request on the same domain. However, looking at a new request header shows that it does not sent the `sessionid` in the header, making the server create a new session, send the new information as a `Set-Cookie` header, and start over the process. If you look at the stored cookies on your computer (with Firefox, right click on the page > `View Page Info`, then `Security` tab, click on `View Cookies`), you can see some cookies for `localhost`, but nothing for `127.0.0.1`. The browser does not set the cookie that it gets from the Ajax call.

## Why?

For so many reason!
We'll list them all on the Solution section. Because the easiest and best way to solve that is not to unlock it, but to use it correctly.

## How to solve it?

1. Here is the first, best, easiest, recommended solution: make your main domain and Ajax call domain match. You will avoid the `CORS` headache, avoid opening a potential security breech, do not handle third-party cookies, and make your development environment consistent with your production.
2. If you really want to handle two different domains, ask yourself if you need it. If you don't, go back to 1. If you really really need it, let's check the solution.

   - First, be sure that your browser accepts third-party cookies. For Firefox, in `Preferences`, go to `Privacy` tab. In the `History` section, select `Firefox will: Use custom settings for history`, and check if `Accept third-party cookies` is set as `Always`. If a visitor disables third-party cookies, your site will be broken for him. (First good reason to go to solution 1.)
   - Second, you have to tell your browser not to ignore the Cookie setting when receiving the reply from the Ajax call. Adding [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) setting to your `xhr` is the solution. Here is the new Javascript code:

     ```
     function call () {
         $.ajax({
             type: 'GET',
             xhrFields: {
                 withCredentials: true
             },
             url: 'http://127.0.0.1/ajax_call/'
         }). [...]
     ```
   - If you try right now, you'll see the browser is still not happy. The reason is

     > Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://127.0.0.1/ajax_call/’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).

     This is a security feature. With this configuration, you open again the security breech which has been blocked by the `CORS` protection. You allow any website to send an authenticated `CORS` request. **Never do that.**
     Using `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` instead of `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL` fixes this issue.
   - Still not done. Your browser now complains for something else:

     > Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax_call/. (Reason: expected ‘true’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Credentials’).

     Again, this is a security feature. Sending credentials through a `CORS` request is most of the time **really bad**. You have to manually allow it on the resource side. You can do it by activating the `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` setting. Your `settings.py` file now looks like this:

     ```
     CORS_URLS_REGEX = r'.*'
     CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
         'localhost',
         '127.0.0.1',
     )
     CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
     ```
   - Now, you can try again, see that it works, and ask yourself again if you really need to have a different domain in your Ajax call.